# Encode selected fields of 3 checkboxes into one string

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have 3 checkboxes where the user can select whatever he wants. I would like to store his selection in the database into one field.

I was thinking of encoding it into a String:

> 0: nothing selected
>       100: first selected
>       101: first & third selected
>   etc.

I think that's a nice way. However, how do I extract the information again? Using substr() to get each checkbox's state?

Is there a better way of encoding/decoding this information?

Thanks a lot
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packing the information into a single database field like this makes queries tricky.  Do you really need to pack the three checkboxes into a single field?  Why not three boolean fields?

If it really must be one field then why strings?  An 8 bit int would be big enough to hold up to 8 checkbox states.